# Oracle procedure stops running

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle stored procedure that is called from a .NET application.  It runs for over 15 minutes.  It is very simple code that inserts into a big table from a smaller table, then clears the smaller table.

My issue is that it runs for like 15 minutes, then it dies.  No error messages in the log.  Nothing.  Just stops running.  I have done a SQL trace, no evidence of an issue.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Some consistencies exist - when it does fail, it never gets to the Data Moved Successfully or Exception section.  Just appears to stop running.

```
PROCEDURE C_X_AllocInsertData(
    p_AccountTable    VARCHAR2,
    p_AllocationTable VARCHAR2,
    p_YearMonth NUMBER, 
    p_versionPK NUMBER,
    p_returncode OUT NUMBER) 
AS PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  v_OutputTableRowCntSql varchar(32767);
BEGIN
  p_returncode:=0;

  C_X_VERSIONINSERTLOG(
    p_VersionPk
   ,'Now moving the data from temp table to big table'
   ,'Now moving the data from temp table to big table'
  );

  --Now that all operations are complete, delete from account table
  v_OutputTableRowCntSql := 'BEGIN delete from '||p_AccountTable||' where YEARMONTH= '||p_YearMonth||'; ';


  --Then insert from the TMP table
  v_OutputTableRowCntSql := v_OutputTableRowCntSql || 'insert into '||p_AccountTable|| ' SELECT * FROM ' || p_AllocationTable||'; ';

  --Then clear the temp table
  v_OutputTableRowCntSql := v_OutputTableRowCntSql ||  'delete from '||p_AllocationTable||'; END;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_OutputTableRowCntSql;
  C_X_VERSIONINSERTLOG(
    p_VersionPk
   ,'Data moved successfully.'
   ,'Data moved successfully.'
  );
  commit;

EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  p_returncode:=-1;

  C_X_VERSIONINSERTLOG(
    p_VersionPk
   ,'Insert into big table failed for version #'||p_versionPK||'... Error message was:  '||SQLERRM
   ,'Insert into big table failed.  Error message was:  '||SQLERRM||' Statement was: '||v_OutputTableRowCntSql
  );
END;
```

It seems that C_X_VERSIONINSERTLOG procedure lacks appropriate error handing...I will add that.  Here it is in its original form...could this be the issue?

```
PROCEDURE C_X_VERSIONINSERTLOG
  (
    P_VERSIONPK       NUMBER,
    P_LOGTEXT VARCHAR2,
    P_ERROR_MSG VARCHAR2)
AS PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  v_VersionLogPk C_X_VERSIONLOG.VersionLogPk%TYPE;
BEGIN

  SELECT C_X_VERSIONLOG_SEQ.nextval INTO v_VersionLogPk FROM DUAL;

  INSERT
  INTO C_X_VERSIONLOG
    (
      VersionLogPk,
      VERSIONPK,
      VERSIONLOGTEXT,
      VERSIONLOGTECHNICALTEXT,
      VERSIONLOGDATE
    )
    VALUES
    (
      v_VersionLogPk,
      P_VERSIONPK,
      P_LOGTEXT,
      P_ERROR_MSG ,
      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
  COMMIT;
END C_X_VERSIONINSERTLOG;
```

Comment: Why tag this as `.net` and `asp.net`? BTW creating sql statements by concatenating field and table names is a recipe for disaster and a security hole whether you do it on the client or the server. A single misspelling will cause your statement to fail. A malicious entry will result in SQL injection. BTW what is the command timeout you use for your connection?

Comment: Panagiotis - Thanks for your reply.  1) We have to use this dynamic SQL...but it is not input by the customer.  2) SQLNET.ORA SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME is set to 180.

Comment: You have a `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler with (apparently) no `RAISE`. Also, why is this in an autonomous transaction? Finally, what does `C_X_VERSIONINSERTLOG` do?

Comment: OK - So I checked the CommandTimeout property on ASP.NET, and it is not set, which means it will default to 30 seconds...but...that cannot be it I don't think because...the procedure usually goes for like 15 minutes before it "dies" without error.

Comment: Jeff - You make an interesting point...I have When Others, but I don't raise any exception - because  I want to catch any and all exceptions, that should not be a problem I don't think...

But you make a good point re C_X_VERSIONINSERTLOG...seems this has no exception handling, it is just an insert statement into the log but maybe there is some issue with it.

Comment: If an exception is raised, your exception handler swallows the error, tries to insert, then doesn't commit anyway, so there is no evidence anything happened. Since you forgot to `RAISE;`, your procedure will act like nothing went wrong. **You need a RAISE.**

Comment: Jeff - I am not so sure here.  I am getting some system exception.  An exception **IS RAISED.**  The system appears to be raising exceptions implicitly.  AT least that is what I am reading.

Comment: At least for debugging, remove all of your exception handling logic and try again.  By default, Oracle will provide all the information you need to debug an error.  My bet is there is an exception in your error handling insert that is getting ignored because it's part of an exception block.